# ZipArchive problem to extracting zip files that have been downloaded from linux server

Tags: php, php-ziparchive

ZipArchive can not extract files when i download a zip file from a linux server.
when I extract files manually and compress them again in windows, then there is no problem.

it seem that could be a problem with line ending in linux and windows zip files.

```
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$zip->open('test.zip'); // zip file has been download from a linux server
$zip->extractTo('./');
$zip->close();
```

any suggestion ?

Comment: What does it mean "ZipArchive can not extract files"? What kind of error do you receive?

Comment: Zip files are binary, so they have nothing to do with newlines. Show us the relevant code, we can't help without it.

Comment: Nothing will happen and i don't get any error. i just download a zip file from server and trying to extracting it so simple but no file will extract.

Comment: Add `error_reporting(-1); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` as first line to your script and try again.

Comment: Where do the zips come from? Are they static, or get generated? Enable display_errors, an error message would definitely help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Downloaded file was corrupt because of sending invalid `Content-Type` header